# Region eu-west-2 not available for aws module boto.ec2 latest

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, boto, elastic-ip

I'm running boto with python3 and I'm running an ansible playbook to setup some ec2 instances.
Everything is fine, creating instances, security groups, key pairs, everything in `eu-west-2`.
When the task for Elastic IPs runs it fails with this message:
`Region eu-west-2 does not seem to be available for aws module boto.ec2. If the region definitely exists, you may need to upgrade boto or extend with endpoints_path`

I'm running ansible with `-e ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/python3"`.
I have latest boto installed.

```
> python3 -m pip freeze | grep boto
 boto==2.44.0
 boto3==1.4.2
 botocore==1.16.19
> python3
 >>> import boto.ec2
 >>> for i in boto.ec2.regions():
 ...   print(i)
 ... 
 RegionInfo:ap-northeast-1
 RegionInfo:ap-northeast-2
 RegionInfo:ap-south-1
 RegionInfo:ap-southeast-1
 RegionInfo:ap-southeast-2
 RegionInfo:ca-central-1
 RegionInfo:cn-north-1
 RegionInfo:eu-central-1
 RegionInfo:eu-west-1
 RegionInfo:sa-east-1
 RegionInfo:us-east-1
 RegionInfo:us-east-2
 RegionInfo:us-gov-west-1
 RegionInfo:us-west-1
 RegionInfo:us-west-2
```

You see that it's missing the `eu-west-2` region ? It should be there. Any ideas ?

The ansible module I'm using is [ec2_eip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ec2_eip_module.html). If this is a limitation of boto how do I force boto3 for that module ?

Comment: boto is the old AWS SDK, you should import boto3 - the last boto release has been in July 2018 - the region didn't exist back then. https://pypi.org/project/boto/#history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to using the community module for elastic ip.
So `community.aws.ec2_eip` instead of `ec2_eip`.